# Extracting HTTP responses from HAR file to filesystem

Tags: extract, har

Is there a tool that can extract documents that appear in HTTP responses and dump them to the filesystem, ideally using path and filenames from the original HTTP requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/outersky/har-tools can extract the response bodies into filesystem hierarchy that reflects the path from HTTP request.